# ASP.Net Add Control "Cannot get inner content of [control] because the contents are not literal."

Tags: asp.net

I am currently trying to dynamically add HTML controls in my web form, but each time I insert a control in another control the error `Cannot get inner content of [control] because the contents are not literal` pops up(when trying to look at innerHtml or innerText) and cannot seem to find the reason why.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
Dim newsList As New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
    newsList.TagName = "ul"
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each newsDR As DataRow In newDS.Tables(0).Rows
        i += 1
        Dim stri As String = i.ToString()
        Dim newsListItem As New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
        newsListItem.TagName = "li"
        newsListItem.ID = "newsListItem" + stri

        Dim newsTitle As New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
        newsTitle.TagName = "h1"
        newsTitle.ID = "newsTitle" + stri
        Dim newsAnchor As New HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor
        newsAnchor.ID = "newsAnchor" + stri
        newsAnchor.InnerHtml = newsDR("NewsTitle")
        newsAnchor.HRef = "#"

        newsTitle.Controls.Add(newsAnchor)

        Dim newsSummary As New HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
        newsSummary.TagName = "div"
        newsSummary.ID = "newsSummary" + stri
        newsSummary.InnerHtml = newsDR("NewsSummary")

        newsListItem.Controls.Add(newsTitle)
        newsListItem.Controls.Add(newsSummary)
        newsList.Controls.Add(newsListItem)
    Next
```

Comment: what line is throwing the error?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use innerHtml after rendering the controls, use RenderControl instead, as stated here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1168614.aspx

Comment: Thanks, using RenderControl works. I was using ICallbackEventHandler interface, so the rendering had already occurred and couldn't use InnerHTML.